# How to tell webpack where to find dynamically imported module?

Tags: webpack, lazy-loading, es6-module-loader

I'm using Webpack's code splitting / lazy loading feature with a dynamic `import` statement. My code looks like that:

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "foo" */'../vendor/foo.js').then(() => {
    // ...
});
```

Webpack correctly splits that into its own `foo` bundle, however when this code gets executed, Webpack tries to load the file from `/foo.js` which results in a 404, as the actual file is served from `/js/foo.js`. How do I tell Webpack not to get it from the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I needed to set [`output.publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath).